# I have One storyboard with different/multiple UIViews and I want a ViewController for each UIView. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have one storyboard with different views, I do not want all the codes in ViewController.swift I would rather have a Swift for each UIView.
Is it possible? and how do I do?

[image]

Comment: If you want to have multiple view controller in single view controller then use container view. If you want swift file for UIView then create a swift file which is a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIContainerView` instead of just `UIView`. When you drag a `UIContainerView` into your storyboard it'll automatically create a View. Just make a new `Cocoa Touch Class` file in your project. Make sure the file is put under `UIViewController`

Then click on the new View that was automatically generated, go to Properties, then select your new Swift file. This connects the View to the file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!